# package resolution failed xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I am running macOS Monterey 12.4 on an M1 MBP with XCode 13.4 installed.

I'm building a swiftUI project for ios and trying to connect a Firebase/FireStore DB to the project using Swift Package Manager and import:  firebase-ios-sdk.

On doing so, I get a Package Resolution Failed message with a box and list of all the firebase-ios-sdk that could not be resolved: list

[Package Resolution failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oziEi.png)

I tried deleting the derived data folder content, resetting package caches, resolving the package version, restart Xcode.  Did not work.

Last night I uninstalled XCode and re-installing Xcode overnight.  Did not work, still the same issue today.

When I import Firebase to the .swiftui file, I get a code error message - No such module 'FirebaseCore'

I will really appreciate your assistance, I am a Newby.

Thanks
Adriaan

Comment: Did you use the XCode File->Add Packages option? And then pick `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git`?

Answer (score 9):

Xcode "File" -> "Packages" -> "Reset Package Caches" solved the issue for me. Hopefully, it will be useful to others as well.

Comment: As crazy and useless as it may sound, do this twice. It fixed the problem for me when I was trying to add a dependency only to a test target and not the whole package

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: (SOLUTION)

Chris Parker @ https://codecrew.codewithchris.com solved the issue for me.

Here is what he wrote and it worked for me:

"I just tried to install Firebase again and the problem still exists. I looked a bit closer to the options that had defaulted with regard to the Dependency rule and the option that had defaulted was “Branch”. I changed that to “Up to the next major version” and the package selections that I was expecting to see did in fact appear so that’s what the problem was."

I just want to say a really big thank you to Chris at codewithchris, he really came through for me.

THANK YOU CHRIS PARKER

Answer (score 1):

1. reset package cache in File-> packages -> Reset Package cache

   or
2. Try to remove and re-add the package.

To remove the package Project -> Package Dependencies -> select your
package and click `-`